# Validation constraint violation: syntax error in element 's:Envelope'

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl

I'm trying connect to FortiAnalyzer to get some info. I saw [here](https://help.fortinet.com/fa/cli-olh/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=FortiAnalyzer_Online_CLI_Reference&file=app_10_3.html) that FortiAnalyzer is providing WSDL and I wrote a simple C# console app in .Net Core. I've successfully added as "Connected Service" with this url: "https://:8080/" (not ending with /FortiAnalyzerWSxml or /FortiAnalyzerWS)

Sample code is like this:

```
var ws = new FortiAnalyzerApi.FortiAnalyzerWSPortTypeClient();
ws.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "api-username";
ws.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "api-password";
ws.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new System.ServiceModel.Security.X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
{
       CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
       RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
};

var result = ws.getSystemStatus(new FortiAnalyzerApi.getSystemStatus());
```

But gives me this error at the last line:

[image]

I don't know is it related to FortiAnalyzer's WSDL. What should I do?

Comment: Did you add certificate?  See : https://help.fortinet.com/fclient/chromebook/1-2-4/FCT-EMS-Admin-Guide/600_Google%20Admin%20Console/0812_Adding%20SSL%20cert%20to%20FAZ.htm

Comment: I've tried. Same problem :(

Comment: Either the XML is failing a schema check of the XML/Schema  has a typo error and is invalid.  You can use an online checker to validate XML or use VS from menu : Project : Add New Item : XML File.  then paste XML into view.  Errors will show up in error list like compiler errors.

Comment: I've validated successfully: https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/service/service/473420631?version=1